# Difference beetwen complément d'objet direct and pronoms accentués

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots, compléments

I want to ask about the difference beetwen two types of pronouns.
For example I can say "Je ne comprends pas vous" and "Je vous ne comprends pas".

Does it mean I can use them alternately?

Comment: Neither of these sentence are French. Should be **je ne vous comprends pas**.

Answer (score 2):

As you've been told *"Je ne comprends pas vous"* is grammatically incorrect.
You're also mistaking if you think that *le pronom vous* in the sentence *"Je ne vous comprends pas"* isn't *un complément d'objet direct*. It is.
- *Je ne comprends pas Pierre.*
Pierre is a **groupe nominal** when used as a **complément d'objet direct**, it is placed **after the verb**.
- *Je ne le comprends pas.*
*Le* is a **pronom personnel complément** when used as a **complément d'objet direct**, it is placed **before the verb** .
**Both** of them are **complément d'objet direct**.

Same goes for a *complément d'objet indirect*.
- *Je souris à Pierre*.
- *Je lui souris*.

*Les compléments d'objet* are functions. They have a grammatical role.
*Les pronoms* are words. They are regulated by grammar.
It doesn't make sense to ask if a function can replace a word. Functions act on words.

Answer (score 1):

No. Both proposal are incorrect. The right sentence is :
**Je ne vous comprends pas.**

But be careful:

- When a stranger say "Je ne vous comprends pas", we understand he don't understand French. (I don't understand what you say)
- When a French say "Je ne vous comprends pas" to another French, it more generally means "I do not understand YOU", i.e. I disagree with you.

Now why **vous** is between **ne** and **vous** ... I don't know, I just speak like my mother teach me !